# JQuery Tab each Selected tab first text box focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

How to set focus to each jQuery UI tabs first textbox? I tried like:

```
var frmObjAT = $j('input[type=button]').closest("form"); 
$j("input[type='text']:first", frmObjAT).focus();
```

First got focus but other tabs not focused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kanishka is right but you have to wrap it with Tabs select event

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
   select: function(event, ui) {
       $(this).find("input[type='text']:first").focus();
   }
});
```

Hope this help.

**Edit reply to comment**.

Jquery added class to hidden tab you can use that.

I tried this works

```
$("#tabs .tabs").not(".ui-tabs-hide").find("input[type='text']:first").focus();
```

Comment: Still text box not focused my full code is  $j( "#tabs" ).tabs({
                    ajaxOptions: {
                        error: function( xhr, status, index, anchor ) {
                   $j( anchor.hash ).html("Error loading Page" );
                        }
                    }, select: function(event, ui) {
                        $j(this).find("input[type='text']:first").focus();
                    },load: function(event, ui) {
                  $j(this).find("input[type='text']:first").focus();
                        $j(".ui-tabs-panel").css('background-color', '#ddddff');} });

Comment: where i put this code whether in my master page or ajax loaded page

Answer (score 0):

this event should fire when the tab is clicked

```
  $('.tab').click(function(){

       $(this).parents("form").find("input[type='text']:first").focus();

    });
```

this should work

**UPDATE**

are those dynamically generated forms, if they are dynamically generated use

```
 live()


  $('.tab').live('click',function(){

       $(this).parents("form").find("input[type='text']:first").focus();

    });
```

Comment: You were right but you have to wrap it with event because he want it in every tab.

Comment: Thanks, It works on first tab only, in second tab not text box not focused

Comment: I write code like this  $j(function() {
                $j("input[type='text']:first", frmObjAT).focus(); } I never triggered any button

Comment: hmm i think your all tabs are in one form . please add your html . and what is this input[type=button]??????. please add some code . else i wont able to help you

Comment: Actually I have 3 tab. Each tab have separate form. When i click any one tab, the text box got focus which is currently selected tab

Comment: Ya $("#tabs .tabs").not(".ui-tabs-hide").find("input[type='text']:first").focus(); this work but it should placed in show option in tab